# Skills for EVE and DUST 514 Gameplay

Tags: eve-online, dust-514

I'm a new player to both EVE and Dust 514. I'm playing Dust with a small group of guys; we don't plan to grow to more than 8. Most of them play only Dust, but I wanted to explore the current interactions of the two games aside from orbital bombardment.

Finding relevant information has been difficult. All I can piece together so far is

- the pilot must be enlisted in Faction Wars (which doesn't impact the Dust corp, just the pilot, for purposes of OB)
- something called Planetary Conquest is involved, which may or may not be related to Planetary Interaction

The second item regarding PI is what's confusing me. I'd like for us to take on more lucrative deals and start fighting for districts, buts me after reading http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Planetary_Conquest it is very unclear how things like districts, jump clones, passive district battles and more actually work for a skills standpoint, if at all, for things like surface infrastructure.

What's the general path for a single pilot whose job is only to earn ISK for the corp and help acquire districts in FW? Is it correct that the PI path is the way to go here?

Comment: You are asking about Dust players, or? Because Planetary Interaction is something EVE players do, while Planetary Conquest is something Dust players do.

Comment: Well that statement may answer my question. My thought was whether actually placing resources on a planet (from the eve pilot) would somehow benefit the dust members in the corp (aside from ISK).

Comment: Planetary Interaction involves mining and refining resources found on planets, and doesn't involve anything to do with Dust514 as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, Planetary Interaction and Planetary Conquest are **not linked in any way** - there was a plan to link them, but it was not implemented.

If you are looking to train an EVE pilot solely for the purpose of faction warfare, then you are looking at solo and small gang PvP, and Orbital Bombardment ships.

Right now the current meta for OB ships is destroyers, because the strike does not gain bonuses from [anything other than number of turrets](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EVE-DUST_514_Link_FAQ#Does_the_turret.27s_damage_multiplier_effect_the_damage_inflicted.3F), and the [OB ammunition is only available in Small size](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EVE-DUST_514_Link_FAQ#Which_weapons_and_ammo_can_I_use.3F). I recommend the Catalyst, Gallente destroyer (though I hate Gallente), solely because it has 8 guns. You can fit any type of gun onto the ship for OB, as the [three strikes do three different sorts of damage](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/EVE-DUST_514_Link_FAQ#Which_weapons_and_ammo_can_I_use.3F).

If you are looking to [make ISK](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Making_ISK) with the pilot as well, I can point you to [any number](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Missions_guide) of [guides](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Advanced_mining) on how to [make money](http://oldforums.eveonline.com/?a=topic&threadID=733552&page=1#1) in EVE. Find something you enjoy doing. I personally recommend [Science and Industry](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Making_ISK#Manufacture) ( i.e. research and manufacturing ) for making money, because on a small scale, you don't really have to pay too much attention to it, and can 'set it and forget it'.